# Running bat file with java processbuilder

Tags: java, batch-file, processbuilder

I am trying to execute .bat file using java process builder but it does not starts the process. Please tell me what i am doing wrong here. This code works fine with linux envoirnment when I replace file.bat with ./file.sh

```
final ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add(WORKING_DIR+File.separator+"file.bat");
final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
try {
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    builder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("Could not start process." ,e);
}
```

Comment: can you post the value of the `WORKING_DIR` variable?

Comment: using java property to get the current working directory System.getProperty("user.dir")

Comment: try to use Runtime Class, here is an example, it will work well, 

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: Which commands are you using in `file.bat` ?

Comment: java -jar netx.jar .....

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: @user2320537: that ought not to make the blindest bit of difference. These days, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` is implemented using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Check your JDK source zip if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 8):

First element in array must be an executable. So you have to invoke cmd.exe in order to call you batch file.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/C", WORKING_DIR + File.separator + "file.bat"}));
```

Comment: still the same problem. it doesn't start the new process and kills the existing one

Comment: You don't have to invoke cmd.exe. A .bat file can be executed. I just wrote a small test case: `import java.io.IOException;

class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
 ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args[0]);
 processBuilder.inheritIO();
 Process process = processBuilder.start();
 process.waitFor();
    }
}`. I have a foo.bat: `echo "Hello, world"`. Then I do `java Test foo.bat`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the path to the bat file is correct. You can either debug it using a debugger or put a sysout to determine that:

```
final ArrayList<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.println("Batch file path : " + WORKING_DIR+File.separator+"file.bat")
command.add(WORKING_DIR+File.separator+"file.bat");
final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
try {
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    builder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("Could not start process." ,e);
}
```