# Why will Java not open up a Batch file when executed with a ProcessBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, batch-file

I've coded a Java program to open up a Batch file that is imported into the resources of the program.

Even by running my code in Eclipse, the Batch file does not work. I have opened the Batch file using the Project Explorer, so the Batch file works.

The file serves, essentially, as a Command Prompt, for when it may be blocked by Group Policies.

The contents of the Batch file are as follows...

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Command Prompt
VER | FIND /I " "
ECHO A portable CMD made with Batch.
ECHO.

CD /D %SYSTEMDRIVE% && CD %USERPROFILE%

:USER
SET /P INPUT="%CD%>"
%INPUT%
ECHO.

GOTO USER
```

Now, when I execute this code:

```
ClassLoader classLoad = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
URL batchPath = classLoad.getResource("cmd.bat");
String batch = batchPath.toString();

System.out.println("batchPath " + batchPath);
System.out.println("batch " + batch);
String batchCommand = batch.replaceFirst("file:/", "");
batchCommand = batchCommand.replace('/', '\\');
batchCommand = batchCommand.replaceAll("%20", " ");

System.out.println(batchCommand);

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("\"" + batchCommand + "\"");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
try {
    Process proc = pb.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

... It appears to throw an error at `Process proc = pb.start()`, which is understandable, really.

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Comment: There are no errors that are thrown. I even have, as shown, a try-catch statement, from which I still do not receive any errors.

Comment: Did you tried to run with debug to check if path is correct?

Comment: Yes, I did try that. Even after doing so, I printed the path to the console, copied it, and executed it in Windows' Run function. In doing so, the Batch file worked as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17120829/524743

First element in array must be an executable. So you have to invoke cmd.exe in order to call you batch file.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/C", "batchCommand"}));
```

Comment: Ah, this worked! Thank you. I suppose this makes sense, considering the `ProcessBuilder` uses the Run function, and that requires program specific commands sometimes.